# Where to install CMU Sphinx adaption files?

Tags: macos, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I've done the various steps to adapt CMU Sphinx using some recorded WAV files. Now where to the resulting files go?
I want to let each user on the system adapt CMU Sphinx  to his own voice, so I don't want  to store the files in /usr/local.

Is there a default directory or do I just have to specify them and their locations every time I run  pocketSphinx?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of adaption you use, the resulting files can be either a transformation matrix which you specify with `-mllr` or a completely new model which is saved where you pointed out to. Adapted model has the same structure as the default one, so yes, you specify them and their locations every time your run the application. See the [official tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialadapt#using_the_model) for more information.

Comment: It seems that there are many different kinds of files. is there some  webpage where all of these are listed and described?  for instance what is a LM file?

Comment: LM stands for *language model*. I don't think there is a page where those files are described, but if you gain some knowledge about how a typical ASR works, the most of questions will be answered. Actually, you don't need to know those files, just follow the examples.